# Dynamically adjust browser fonts not to overflow the width

Tags: linux, browser, fonts, iceweasel

I use Iceweasel at the moment since I'm on a Debian system, but I have no problem changing browser to whatever would work on my system. So, feel free to answer my question for any browser, plugin module, or whatever.

I like large fonts because of eye problems (I always use a projector). At the same time, I think it is annoying when a page is too wide to fit so you have to scroll left and right. Wouldn't it be cool with a dynamic font size, like "as big as possible, but still not overflowing the width"?

If there is no such solution for any browser, I realize this is a lot to ask for. I'm not expecting anyone to paste five lines of code to solve the problem.

Comment: It is policy to ask only **one question at a time**, as this makes it easier to focus answers and comments on one actual problem. Feel free to post your other questions separately though.

Comment: I understand how you feel. Unfortunately scaling is never looked into because very few users blow up dpi and use max zoom. I ad a web developer do not even have a minute  designated for making our sites handicap friendly. :(  usually things like this get developed by the people asking for it.